# Commutator of Lie derivative

Tags: lie-groups, lie-derivative

(this question uses physics conventions, which might differ by factors of $i$ from pure math conventions)

Suppose I have a Lie group $G$ with generators $T_i$. Their commutator is $$[T_i,T_j] = if_{ijk}T_k$$ with some structure constants $f_{ijk}$. Furthermore, the (left-) Lie derivative of any scalar function $g:G\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$$ \partial_ig(U) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\left(g(e^{ihT_i}U)-g(U)\right) $$.

**Question**: what is the commutator $[\partial_i,\partial_j]=?$ It should intuitively be proportional to $f_{ijk}\partial_k$. But what is the correct sign? My sources (such as Eq. 5.3 in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/ptps/article/doi/10.1143/PTPS.111.293/1890667)) indicate it should be $-f_{ijk}\partial_k$. But my calculation comes out as $+f_{ijk}\partial_k$. Would appreciate if someone could show me my error.

**My calculation:**
\begin{align}
[\partial_i,\partial_j]g(U)
&= \partial_i \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\left(g(e^{ihT_j}U)-g(U)\right) - (i\leftrightarrow j) \\
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h^2}\left(g(e^{ihT_j}e^{ihT_i}U) - g(e^{ihT_j}U)-g(e^{ihT^i}U)+g(U)\right) - (i\leftrightarrow j) \\
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h^2}\Big(g(\underbrace{e^{ihT_j}e^{ihT_i}}_{=e^{ihT_i}e^{ihT_j}e^{-h^2[T_j,T_i]}+O(h^3)}U) - g(e^{ihT_i}e^{ihT_j}U)\Big) \\
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h^2}\Big(g(e^{ihT_i}e^{ihT_j}e^{-h^2[T_j,T_i]}U) - g(e^{ihT_i}e^{ihT_j}U)\Big) \\
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h^2}\Big(g(e^{-h^2[T_j,T_i]}U) - g(U)\Big) \\
&= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h^2}\Big(g(e^{ih^2 f_{ijk}T_k}U) - g(U)\Big) \\
&= f_{ijk}\partial_k g(U)
\end{align}

**alternative approach**
consider $\partial_i$ as a linear operator on the space of (sufficiently smooth) scalar functions on $G$. Then
\begin{align}
([\partial_i,\partial_j]g)(U)
&=(\partial_i\partial_j g)(U) - (i\leftrightarrow j) \\
&=\lim_h\frac{1}{h}\left((\partial_j g)(e^{ihT_i}U) - (\partial_j g)(U)\right) - (i\leftrightarrow j) \\
\end{align}

and now it should be
\begin{align}
(\partial_j g)(e^{ihT_i}U)
&= \lim_h\frac{1}{h}\left(g(e^{ihT_j} e^{ihT_i}U) - g(e^{ihT_i})\right)
\end{align}

which gets me to the same (presumably wrong) result.

Comment: Did you mean Lie algebra instead of Lie group?

Comment: $G$ is a Lie group, $U\in G$. And $T_i$  is in the Lie algebra.

Comment: sorry, this might be physics-lingo. "generators of the lie group" is usually understood to be "basis elements of its associated lie algebra".

Comment: I think in the first term of the second line you should invert the roles of T_j and T_i if I understood correctly your conventions: you ar $\partial_i$ deriving something that has to be evaluated at $e^{ihT_j}U$.

Comment: @N.Ciccoli You are probably right, but I dont really understand it. I thought the derivative should always be with respect to $U$, so the function to be differentiated by $\partial_i$ is $g(e^{ihT_j}\cdot)$.

Comment: The derivative is *not* w.r.t. $U$. If you set $f_j(U,t) = g(e^{itT_j}U)$ then $$\partial_j g(U) = \partial_t f_j(U,0).$$